# What is driver with fwLP tag?

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, windows-7, driver

There is fwLP tag in memory on Windows. I searched info in web about this tag, but nothing detailed. What about driver or something else this tag?

Answer (score 0):

It's AVG driver - avgNetHub.sys